# Selenium XPath - Ignore element amongst table

Tags: selenium, xpath

I have an issue with selecting a table to be read in Selenium.
I have a table in which there is two 'tr' elements inside the 'thead', and I need to find a way to ignore the first of these.
Here is the code:

```
<table class="noselect">
    <thead>
      <tr>
         <th> </th>
         <th class="number IOL">Interest Rates</th>
         <th class="number IO">
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th>Description</th>
         <th class="number">Value</th>
         <th class="number">Percentage</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
      <tr class="">
      <tr class="">
      <tr class="">
      <tr>
      <tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Using Selenium I will ask it to record the value of a certain row and column . This will then look at the Table element I will give it (hopefully using an XPath I can get working in this case), look at the thead and record the headers of each column. In this case that I am struggling with, the fact there is an extra 'tr' at the top of this table gets in the way of this process.

This is how the element is currently used:

```
[TableAlias("Detailed table")]
protected virtual IWebElement DetailedTable()
{
    return Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//table[@class='noselect']"));
}
```

I have tried many different ways which I can't get to work, but the gist of what I've been going for is:

```
//table[@class='noselect movements']/thead/tr/th[not(text()='Interest Rates')]/../../..
```

Here I'm stuck on going to the 'tr' element, telling it not to use it then backing out, but that selects it back again - and even that doesn't unselect the whole 'tr' element. It doesn't seem to help (to me) that the 'tr' element I'm trying to remove is blank with no class or defining features.

Is there a way of selecting the entire table except for the first 'tr' element in 'thead' as one element?

Comment: what do you mean with "select the entire table"? what do you wanna do with the table later? that's important to answer your question, so better describe what you really want to achieve (and where is the xpath you already tried?)

Comment: Using Selenium I will ask it to record the value of a certain row and column . This will then look at the Table element I will give it (hopefully using an XPath I can get working in this case), look at the thead and record the headers of each column. In this case that I am struggling with, the fact there is an extra 'tr' at the top of this table gets in the way of this process. I will add this and the XPath's that I have tried using to the post

Answer (score 1):

combine two xpathes. The 1st xpath take thead without the 1st tr and the 2nd  tbody

```
//table/thead/tr[not(position()=1)] | //table/tbody
```

Comment: This does work in the sense that it selects everything that I needed, but unfortunately it is seen as two separate elements, so when Selenium goes to use it it only ends up seeing the first of the two XPaths in that. If I can find a way of getting Selenium to combine the two elements, this would be perfect

Comment: @StevieBruce unfortunatly, i know nothing about selenium. But it works fine in xpath testers

Answer (score 0):

In your function that processes the `THEAD` tag, get the collection of `TR`s and start with [1] (skipping [0]) and process the rest.

Comment: Good idea, I get the feeling this might be the best way to do it. Issue is there are lots of tests already that use this function, and doing this will stop those from working, but I can just duplicate that code and make a new process specially for this issue. Thanks

Comment: I haven't seen that function but if there is a lot of shared code, I would try to merge the two together, if at all possible, to minimize shared code.